# How to change keycloak jvm arguments via CLI in standalone configuration

Tags: heap-memory, keycloak, jvm-arguments

Is there any way to change JVM arguments via command line interface?
I connected CLI using `/opt/keycloak/bin/jboss-cli.sh -c controller=127.0.0.1:9990`
but couldn't able to set the JVM arguments.I could see via `ps -aef | grep keycloak` default heap size and max heap size is `-Xms64m -Xmx512m`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set in `standalone.conf` or set environment variable `JAVA_OPTS` before calling `standalone.sh`. But be aware that it will overwrite all default settings.

Comment: Hi Ravthiru , yeah you are right we can set there , I tried it and it worked also but my problem is can we pass this as a command line argument while keycloak startup ?we are not supposed to change directly standalone.conf

Comment: I tried setting set `"JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xms1024m -Xmx2048m"` and then calling `/opt/keycloak/bin/standalone.sh -b $BIND_IP --server-config $standalonexml & `  but it is taking always whatever is configured in standalone.conf

Comment: Please have a look this [link](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Command+line+parameters) from Jboss official documents and see supported command line arguments you can pass .

Answer (score 0):

commons.sh script is executed in the standalone.sh

It is better to have additional JAVA_OPTS in common.sh without changing the standalon.sh

Add the below entry in the common.sh

```
DEFAULT_MODULAR_JVM_OPTIONS="$DEFAULT_MODULAR_JVM_OPTIONS -Dkeycloak.profile.feature.upload_scripts=enabled"
```

Comment: This does not apply to v20. common.sh is no longer a script as far as I can tell. I'm trying out JAVA_OPTS_APPEND instead.